# How to combine and simplify the following PostScript operators?

Tags: pstricks, postscript

### Background

Let

```
\def\RR#1{(2^(#1/10))}
\def\TT#1{(#1)}
```

be the radius and angle functions, respectively.

[Christoph defined a PS operator `AAA` as follows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/147182/19356).

```
/AAA {AlgParser cvx exec exch AlgParser cvx exec exch RadtoDeg PtoC} def
```

It can be used to translate

```
\pscircle*[linecolor=red](!\RR{7*Pi/2} \TT{7*Pi/2} AAA){2pt}
```

from polar infix to polar postfix. However `7*Pi/2` are repeated, it breaks DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle and cannot make use of `t` as explained shortly below.

I modified [Herbert's operators](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/133885/19356) as follows

```
/BBB {/TT ED TT AlgParser cvx /t ED  /RR ED RR AlgParser cvx /r ED r t RadtoDeg PtoC} def
/CCC { AlgParser cvx /t ED  AlgParser cvx exec t RadtoDeg PtoC} def
```

to allow me to write two styles as follows.

```
\pscircle*[linecolor=green](!{(2^(t/10))} {(3*Pi/2)} BBB){2pt}
\pscircle*[linecolor=blue](!\RR{t} \TT{5*Pi/2} CCC){2pt}
```

The first does not make use of `\RR` and `\TT` and the last does make use of `\RR` and `\TT`.

### Complete code

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\pstVerb
{
    /AAA {AlgParser cvx exec exch AlgParser cvx exec exch RadtoDeg PtoC} def 
    /BBB {/TT ED TT AlgParser cvx /t ED  /RR ED RR AlgParser cvx /r ED r t RadtoDeg PtoC} def
    /CCC { AlgParser cvx /t ED  AlgParser cvx exec t RadtoDeg PtoC} def
}


\def\RR#1{(2^(#1/10))}
\def\TT#1{(#1)}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-3,-3)(3,3)
  \psplot[algebraic,polarplot]{TwoPi}{TwoPi 2 mul}{\RR{x}}
    \pscircle*[linecolor=red](!\RR{7*Pi/2} \TT{7*Pi/2} AAA){2pt}
    \pscircle*[linecolor=green](!{(2^(t/10))} {(3*Pi/2)} BBB){2pt}
    \pscircle*[linecolor=blue](!\RR{t} \TT{5*Pi/2} CCC){2pt}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

### Question

Can I combine `BBB` and `CCC` to create `DDD` as simple as `AAA` but they must still work for the following?

```
\pscircle*[linecolor=green](!{(2^(t/10))} {(3*Pi/2)} DDD){2pt}
\pscircle*[linecolor=blue](!\RR{t} \TT{5*Pi/2} DDD){2pt}
```

Bonus question: I still don't understand why Herbert used only one `exec` while Christoph used 2 `exec`s? What does `exec` do actually?

Comment: What about defining `\def\RT#1{\RR{#1} \TT{#1}}` and calling `\pscircle*[linecolor=red](!\RT{7*Pi/2} AAA){2pt}`, so that DRY is not broken ?

Comment: @AdamB. But now there is a constraint more, `\RR` cannot be represented as an expression with `t` when passed as a point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

simplified

```
/AAA {AlgParser cvx exec exch AlgParser cvx exec exch RadtoDeg PtoC} def 
/BBB {exec AlgParser cvx /t ED  exec AlgParser cvx exec t RadtoDeg PtoC} def
/CCC {AlgParser cvx /t ED  AlgParser cvx exec t RadtoDeg PtoC} def
```

for `/BBB`: the expression `{(2^(t/10))}` is moved to PostScript *with* the parentheses `{...}` the reason why we first need an `exec` for removing it, or, of course, `/anyvar exch def anyvar` or `/anyvar ED anyvar` (saving it and pushing the saved data onto the stack) will do the same. Without the `{...}` it can't work on *TeX* side.

For your examples you need only `/BBB`, it works for all:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\pstVerb{
  /A2P {exec AlgParser cvx /t ED  exec AlgParser cvx exec t RadtoDeg PtoC} def }

\def\RR#1{(2^(#1/10))}
\def\TT#1{(#1)}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-3,-3)(3,3)
  \psplot[algebraic,polarplot]{2 Pi mul neg}{4 Pi mul}{\RR{x}}
  \pscircle*[linecolor=red  ](!\RR{7*Pi/2} \TT{7*Pi/2} A2P){2pt}
  \pscircle*[linecolor=green](!{(2^(t/10))} {(3*Pi/2)} A2P){2pt}
  \pscircle*[linecolor=blue ](!\RR{t} \TT{5*Pi/2} A2P){2pt}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Only the bonus answer regarding the `exec`:

`AlgParser` parses a string `(...)` and leaves an array `[...]` on the stack. The expression

```
(2^(Pi/10)) AlgParser
```

evaluates to the array

```
[tx@AddMathFunc begin 2.0 Pi 10.0 div exp end]
```

In order to evaluate this, one must turn this into an *executable array* (or *procedure*) with `cvx`, which gives

```
{tx@AddMathFunc begin 2.0 Pi 10.0 div exp end}
```

Now you can either call `exec` to execute this procedure which is on the stack (which is what I did twice), or you can save it and execute it by calling the variable, i.e. use `/x exch def x` to execute it (which is what Herbert did once).

So the following statements are equal

```
(2^(Pi/10)) AlgParser cvx exec
```

and

```
(2^(Pi/10)) AlgParser cvx /x exch def x
```

Comment: you also need the `cvx` when saving the expression

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to Christoph's answer on `exec`, I managed to make a `DDD` working in both cases. Here is the MWE (Minimal Working Example).

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\pstVerb
{
    /AAA {AlgParser cvx exec exch AlgParser cvx exec exch RadtoDeg PtoC} def 
    /DDD {exec AlgParser cvx /t ED exec AlgParser cvx exec t RadtoDeg PtoC} def
}    

\def\RR#1{(2^(#1/10))}
\def\TT#1{(#1)}
\def\RT#1{\RR{#1} \TT{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-3,-3)(3,3)
  \psplot[algebraic,polarplot]{2 Pi mul neg}{4 Pi mul}{\RR{x}}
  \pscircle*[linecolor=red](!\RT{7*Pi/2} AAA){2pt}
  \pscircle*[linecolor=green](!{(2^(t/10))} {(3*Pi/2)} DDD){2pt}
  \pscircle*[linecolor=blue](!\RR{t} \TT{5*Pi/2} DDD){2pt}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `DDD` works for all ...

Comment: @Herbert I actually just tested it in replacement of `BBB` and `CCC`, but yes it works for all